# Convert values of a dictionary into key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a sample dictionary

```
sample_dict = [{"id":1, "count":10},
               {"id":2, "count":20},
               {"id":3, "count":30}]
```

I want something like this

```
sample_dict = [{1: 10}, {2: 20}, {3: 30}]
```

how can I do this optimally?

Comment: What does your unoptimal solution look like?

Comment: Currently I am iterating through the list and getting the values of "id" and "count" and creating a new dict and appending it to another list

Comment: @Logan what is unoptimal about that?

Comment: Please show your code, so that we can write more optimal solution

Comment: Your sample is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary, and the result is also a list of dictionaries.

Comment: [{d['id']: d['count']} for d in sample_dict]

Comment: The List comprehension is neat but I wanted a way in which we can get the results without iterating through the whole loop, Maybe a function or method which can does that or so

Comment: @Logan So write a function that does it using the list comprehension (or `map`, if you prefer that). You can't create a new list of new dictionaries from the original without iterating through the whole thing; if there were a library function, it's what it would do.

Comment: Map version -> `list(map(lambda x:{x['id']:x['count']},sample_dict))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a single object like this:

```py
sample_dict = [{"id":1, "count":10},{"id":2, "count":20},{"id":3, "count":30}]

out = { o['id']: o['count'] for o in sample_dict }
print(out) # {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30}
print(out[2]) # 20
```

Note that although the `id` and `count` values are in-order, this is not a requirement for this method. So long as the `id` values are unique, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

```py
sample_dict = [{"id":1, "count":10},
               {"id":2, "count":20},
               {"id":3, "count":30}]

output = []
for elem in sample_dict:
    new_dict = {elem["id"]: elem["count"]}
    output.append(new_dict)
```

Printing output will return

```py
print(output)

[{1: 10}, {2: 20}, {3: 30}]
```